# R shiny data table is displayed locally but not in deployment

Tags: r, shiny, deployment

The freTD8890 table is generated from the lifecontingencies library.

renderDataTable works fine locally but not in deployment

I think this has to be caused by

> Warning: Error in eval: object 'freTD8890' not found

This is my R app

```r
library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)
library(shinydashboard)
library(plotly)
library(DT)
library(lifecontingencies)

# Define UI
ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "A"),
  dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(
      tabItem("donnes",
              h2("Les donnes"),
              dataTableOutput("d")
      ),
      tabItem(tabName = "Modeles",
              h2("Lois parametriques usuelles"),
              
              h3("Gompertz"),
              div("ce loi estime les probabilites de survie pour la vente de rentes viageres")
              
              
      )
    ) 
  ),
  dashboardBody()
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$d<- renderDataTable(freTD8890)
} 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

And this is the app logs

> 2022-02-23T22:37:05.342692+00:00 shinyapps[5720786]: BugReport:
> https://github.com/spedygiorgio/lifecontingencies/issues
> 2022-02-23T22:37:05.486614+00:00 shinyapps[5720786]:
> 2022-02-23T22:37:05.342693+00:00 shinyapps[5720786]:
> 2022-02-23T22:37:05.342690+00:00 shinyapps[5720786]:   Kevin J Owens
> [ctb], 2022-02-23T22:37:05.342691+00:00 shinyapps[5720786]:   Ivan
> Williams [ctb] 2022-02-23T22:37:05.342690+00:00 shinyapps[5720786]:
> Ernesto Schirmacher [ctb], 2022-02-23T22:37:05.342690+00:00
> shinyapps[5720786]:   Gian Paolo Clemente [ctb]
> (https://orcid.org/0000-0001-6795-4595),
> 2022-02-23T22:37:05.342692+00:00 shinyapps[5720786]: Version:  1.3.8
> 2022-02-23T22:37:09.394681+00:00 shinyapps[5720786]: Warning: Error in
> eval: object 'freTD8890' not found 2022-02-23T22:37:09.403969+00:00
> shinyapps[5720786]:   124: eval 2022-02-23T22:37:09.403969+00:00
> shinyapps[5720786]:   123: eval 2022-02-23T22:37:09.403970+00:00
> shinyapps[5720786]:   120: dotloop 2022-02-23T22:37:09.403972+00:00
> shinyapps[5720786]:   117: widgetFunc 2022-02-23T22:37:09.403970+00:00
> shinyapps[5720786]:   119: req 2022-02-23T22:37:09.403971+00:00
> shinyapps[5720786]:   118: exprFunc 2022-02-23T22:37:09.403972+00:00
> shinyapps[5720786]: htmlwidgets 2022-02-23T22:37:09.403972+00:00
> shinyapps[5720786]: shinyRenderWidget 2022-02-23T22:37:09.403973+00:00
> shinyapps[5720786]:   115: func 2022-02-23T22:37:09.403972+00:00
> shinyapps[5720786]:   116: :: 2022-02-23T22:37:09.403973+00:00
> shinyapps[5720786]:   102: renderFunc 2022-02-23T22:37:09.403997+00:00
> shinyapps[5720786]:   101: renderFunc 2022-02-23T22:37:09.404000+00:00
> shinyapps[5720786]:    13: fn

Comment: Are you sure your data is included when you deploy?

Comment: `freTD8890` is defined nowhere in your code and isn't exported by `lifecontingencies`. You probably created it yourself and forgot to include the code in your app